# Apache pdfbox .doc to .pdf conversion

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, doc

I'm trying to convert `.doc` to `.pdf`, but I got this **exception** and I don't know how to fix it.

```
java.io.IOException: Missing root object specification in trailer
at   org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseTrailerValuesDynamically(COSParser.java:2042)
```

This is where the exception is thrown:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(convertDocToPdf(documentInputStream));
```

Here is my conversion method:

```
private byte[] convertDocToPdf(InputStream documentInputStream) throws Exception {
    Document document = null;
    WordExtractor we = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
    byte[] documentByteArray = null;
    try {
        document = new Document();
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(documentInputStream);

        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        we = new WordExtractor(doc);
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

        Range range = doc.getRange();
        document.open();
        writer.setPageEmpty(true);
        document.newPage();
        writer.setPageEmpty(true);

        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph pr = range.getParagraph(i);
            paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n", "");
            document.add(new Paragraph(paragraphs[i]));
        }
        documentByteArray = out.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        throw new Exception(STATE.FAILED_CONVERSION.name());
    } finally {
        document.close();
        try {
            we.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return documentByteArray;
}
```

Comment: PdfWriter - isn't that itext? And what version of PDFBox are you using? Could you upload your PDF? And why is "writer.close()" never called?

Comment: Is your question about iText or about Pdfbox? They are competing products.

Comment: @Amadee still one can use both side by side. One must be aware of different architectures, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use iText classes and do

```
documentByteArray = out.toByteArray();
```

before you finish the document

```
document.close();
```

Thus, the `documentByteArray` only contains an incomplete PDF which PDFBox complains about.